# My prefix is a virus, my infix is a syllable note

Tags: riddle

Another Riley riddle:

> My prefix is a virus,
> My infix is a table.
> My suffix is a syllable note,
> I together am an instrument

Hint:

> The "table" n line 2 is a "Lookup table"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe

> Flute

Prefix

> Flu https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Influenza

Infix

> Lut https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table

Suffix

> Te https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge (Ti?)

Comment: Yes, you are right.